# How do I set my laptop default time/timezone to Asia/Dubai

Tags: python-3.x, timezone

How do I set my laptop's default time/timezone to Asia/Dubai?

I tried this:

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dubai');

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What's the output after you execute that function? Also, this is in PHP, not python-3.x

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.